# Android Studio Rendering Issues

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am using Android Studio 1.0.1 .
When i am trying to add a button or any other element , the following error occurs

```
Exception raised during rendering: Color value 'D:\android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\sdk\platforms\android-19\data\res\color\secondary_text_holo_light.xml' must start with #
```

Comment: your color value is missing the pound sign "#" for example `android:background="#ff0"`

Comment: @Biu I got this and mine had a full pound sign and valid color.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error too. For me worked:

1. Go to colors.xml
2. Select one of your color
3. Refactor -> Rename (Shift + F6) (no need to remove "_" as David Shedrow says)

...and voilá, rendering problems are gone.

PS: After that you can again rename the color name back to original name

Comment: This probably kicks in some sort of re-build that fixes the issue "temporarily" as it can come back later on.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in android

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=70110

Comment: How do i overcome this ??

Comment: I don't know. Keep an eye on that issue. I guess there will be a workaround postet in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error with the name hackit_1 when I removed the _ (a legal symbol) and changed the drawable name to hackit1 the error disappeared.